# Check if a webcam is available/unavailable using EMGU.CV

Tags: vb.net, webcam-capture, emgucv

I am working with multiple webcams in VB.NET using EMGU.CV, specifically for Recording Video Realtime.

The problem is, when a camera is unplugged or suddenly malfunctioned, I need the `PictureBox` containing the image capture to display only nothing.

I am working with this code:

```
    Try
                '===================== CAM 1
                imagez0 = Capturez0.RetrieveBgrFrame
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = imagez0.ToBitmap()
                Videoz.WriteFrame(imagez0)
                drawbitmap1 = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
                graph = Graphics.FromImage(drawbitmap1)
                graph.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                graph.DrawString(x + " | CAM 1 | Faculty", Label1.Font, brush, PictureBox1.Location)
                PictureBox1.Image = drawbitmap1
            Catch ex As Exception
                Capturez0.Stop()
                imagez0 = Nothing
                Videoz.WriteFrame(imagez0)
                PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
                Videoz = Nothing
End Try
```

But when I try to unplug the webcam, it only hangs on the last image it captures and then does nothing, just hangs on that image. I think the code did not fall to the `Catch exception` that is why the image is still available.

Then when I try to put the camera back, it won't resume recording. Its just there stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect accidental USB unplug then you can have a `Timer control` which will check for input device list as described in following [link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getrawinputdevicelist)

You can also refer to this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/18511/webcam-using-directshow-net). It describes all the functions you need to work with a Web Cam.

**Other useful Links**

- [Emgu CV Camera Capture Documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture)

Comment: I tried putting it on a Timer, still no luck. I got the same results.